# Nextcord typing through discord bot

Tags: nextcord

I would like to be able to asynchronously send inputs to my python terminal and have my bot output them, whilst also keeping my other event running.

```
import nextcord
import botToken #contains the string of my bot token
from nextcord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    general = client.get_channel(925388635304521859)
    while True:
        inp = input("->")
        if len(inp) < 4001:
            await general.send(inp)
        else:
            await general.send(inp[0: 1500])

@client.event
async def on_message(message): #its supposed to react to each message with a buffalo emoji
    print(message.content)
    channel = message.channel
    if "<@!308022163330564099>" in message.content:
        await message.delete()
        await channel.send("")
    await message.add_reaction("")

client.run(botToken.TOKEN)e
```

Currently the on_ready() event only loads when it starts which is good, but i would like it to be asyncronic if thats a possibility. I don't know much about nextcord so I have no ideas. I would love any ideas for this.

Answer (score 0):

The tasks extension in Nextcord may help for what you are trying to do

https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html

It allows you to execute code in the background using a loop.

```py
from nextcord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(seconds=1.0)
async def my_task_loop():
    print("Hello!")

@my_task_loop.before_loop
async def before_my_task_loop():
    print('waiting for ready')
    await self.bot.wait_until_ready()

my_task_loop.start()
```